# How can I make sure I have data before component mounts?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, prisma

A user clicks on a link and client reads token from url. Then the token is passed to `signup` mutation. On the backend I have that token saved to the user so I can query and find that user. The issue is that I get an error on the client side `GraphQL error: No user found`. I presume that the token is not passed to mutation `signup(shortLivedToken: String)` that's why I can't query the user on the backend. In graphql playground everything works as expected. I know that I get the token from url because it's in `props.match.params.token` Here's my frontend `SignUp` component:

```
class SignUp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { shortLivedToken: props.match.params.token }
  }

  handleMutation = async mutation => {
    try {
      const res = await mutation()
      console.log(res)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
    // const token = res.data.signUp.token
    // localStorage.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN, token)
    // this.setState({ error: e.message })
    // }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Mutation
        mutation={SIGN_UP}
        variables={{ shortLivedToken: this.state.shortLivedToken }}
      >
        {(mutation, { data, loading, error }) => {
          if (loading)
            return (
              <Pane
                display="flex"
                alignItems="center"
                // justifyContent="center"
                height={400}
              >
                <Spinner />
              </Pane>
            )
          if (error)
            return (
              <Pane
                display="flex"
                alignItems="center"
                justifyContent="center"
                height={400}
              >
                <p>{this.props.match.params.token}</p>
                <Text>Error occurred {error.message}</Text>
              </Pane>
            )
          this.handleMutation(mutation)
          return null
        }}
      </Mutation>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: calling this.handleMutation during rendering seems odd to me. Normally you would assign the mutation function as a form submit handler or a button onclick handler. I guess calling it during render is just not the way to go. I don't see a need to copy state to props neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `handleMutation` should not be called from render, you can use `graphql` HOC from react-apollo and get the mutation in props and use it in react lifecycle method to fetch the data.

```
graphql(SIGN_UP, {
  name: 'signUp'
})(SignUp)

componentDidMount () {
  this.props.signUp({
    variables: {
      shortLivedToken: this.props.match.params.token
    }
  })
}
```

your `handleMutation` function should be like below mentioned:

```
handleMutation = async mutation => {
try {
  const res = await mutation({variables: this.props.match.params.token})
  console.log(res)
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
// const token = res.data.signUp.token
// localStorage.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN, token)
// this.setState({ error: e.message })
// }
```

}

and you can call this Function from `componentDidMount` as well.

Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you, sir. This works well. Could you elaborate a little bit more why this can not be done using  `Mutation` renderprop and calling `handleMutation` from render?

Comment: It's not a good idea to change react `state` from render function, it will trigger the render function again. and Mutation render props provides a `mutation` function which should be triggering via some action. `Mutation` is something which alters the data, and data manipulates mostly handled over some event.